# Create a trigger for update

Tags: sql

I would like to create an update trigger, so that it will update the column named resignationdate with a date based on the EmpActive column once it change it value to false.

Both columns are located on the same table called tblEmployee.

Thanks

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Only a very few of them have ANSI SQL triggers implemented.)

Comment: also show some example  for `update the column named resignationdate with a date based on the EmpActive column once it change it value to false`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a table with such structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tblEmployee (
  resignationdate DATETIME,
  EmpActive       BIT
)
```

you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblEmployeeTrig
  ON tblEmployee
FOR UPDATE AS
  BEGIN
    IF (
         SELECT EmpActive
         FROM INSERTED) = 0
      UPDATE tblEmployee
      SET resignationdate = getdate()
    --WHERE {some conditions}
  END
```

This is Sybase ASE syntax, but I guess it's close to any other DBMS syntax.

You can test it like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblEmployee VALUES (getdate(), 1)
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee
```

And now fire the trigger:

```
UPDATE tblEmployee
SET EmpActive = 0
```

Comment: "I guess it's close" - only Sybase and Microsoft SQL Server, so far as I'm aware, have a set-based trigger with `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables. A lot of other products have per-row triggers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But that's all I can help the topic's owner *_*